# Proving series is divergent by definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I was trying to prove the divergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$

when $a_n$ is defined by $a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & n\enspace is \enspace odd\\ \frac{1}{n^3} & n\enspace is \enspace even \end{cases}$
I tried to do the following but I feel like I am missing something.
Let us denote the (2n-1)th partial sum of $a_n$ by $S_{2n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4^3} + ... + \frac{1}{2n-1}$ therefore :
$S_{2n-1} \geq 1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + ... + \frac{1}{2n-1} = T_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2n-1} $
$T_n$ is the n-th partial sum of $\sum \frac{1}{2n-1}$ which is divergent therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} T_n = \infty$ .
Therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty}S_{2n-1} = \infty$ and therefore the series is divergent.
My problem is that I am not sure about the last step which and if whether or not $\lim_{n \to \infty}S_{2n-1} = \infty$ implies that the series is divergent, do I have also to consider the sequence $S_{2n}$ in order to determine that the series is divergent?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your work looks fine, not forgetting to mention that your series is positive and thus the comparison test is appliable.

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh thanks alot!! I completely forgot about the comparison test here... Silly me :). It makes the problem so much easier

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prove that $\lim S_n = +\infty$ then you must consider $S_{2n}$, writing for example $S_{2n}>S_{2n-1}$ combined with $S_{2n-1} \to +\infty$ is sufficient.

If you just want to prove that $S_n$ is not convergent in $\mathbb{R}$, then writing that there is one subsequence that is not convergent is sufficient.

Comment: Okay I get it, for the divergence I don't necessarily need to prove that $lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \infty$ so I guess that what I showed is enough.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**Shortcut**

All of the terms are positive.

Ignore the even terms.  The odd terms, by themselves are strictly greater than $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \times ~\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}~$ (i.e. the harmonic series), which is known to be divergent (i.e. goes to $\infty$).

$\frac{1}{2} \times \infty = ~$ (informally) $~\infty$.

That is, since your series is greater than (1/2) of a divergent series (i.e. a series that goes to $\infty$), your series must also go to $\infty$ (i.e. must also be divergent).

---

See also the comments following this answer.

Comment: You cannot ignore terms of a series sequence to say something about its sequence of partial sums, which is what you are trying, imo, to do.

Comment: @DonAntonio Every element of the sequence is positive.  Replace all of the even terms with $(0)$, and you have $(1/2)$ of a divergent series, which is therefore divergent.  The given series is greater than the series where the even terms are all replaced by $(0)$, because all of the terms in the series are positive.

Comment: Indeed so...but that's exacly what the OP already did with the sunsequence of partial sums $\;S_{2n-1}\;$ and that's enough.

Comment: @DonAntonio I disagree.  Let $S_n$ be the sequence of partial sums of the given series and let $H_n$ be $(1/2)$ times the sequence of partial sums of the harmonic series.  Every element in $S_n$is greater than the corresponding element in the divergent sequence $H_n$.

Comment: What exactly do you disagree with? The OP showed the subsequence of partial sums $\;S_{2n-1}\;$ diverges to $\;\infty\;$ . That means the sequence of partial sums cannot converge to a real number. That's enough to conclude the series is divergent. Or perhaps you disagree with something else?

Comment: @DonAntonio Your 1st and 2nd comments, following my answer indicated that I could not ignore specific (positive) terms in the series, and that my answer was therefore insufficient.  That is what I disagree with.  My answer did not focus only on the $S_{2n-1}$ partial sums.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by making contradictions: Assume $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ is convergent.

Since all terms are positive, it is absolutely convergent, so no worries about rearrangement.

$$\sum_{n\in odd}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n -\sum_{n\in even}^\infty a_n$$

Based on our assumption, the RHS is convergent, so the LHS is convergent. But we know the LHS is actually divergent due to p-series test. Therefore, we get a contradiction.